# Correct defintion polynomial-time reduction

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, complexity-classes

I have frequently seen two different definitions of polynomial-time reduction. In the following let $A, B \subseteq \Sigma^*$ be decidable problems. I will try to formulate the definitions in my own words:

Definition 1: $A \le_{p_1} B$ iff there exists a polynomial-time computable function $f\colon \Sigma^*\to\Sigma^*$ such that for all $w\in\Sigma^*$:

$$\begin{equation}
w\in A \iff f(w) \in B.\tag{1}
\end{equation}$$

Definition 2: $A \le_{p_2} B$ iff assuming we have a Turing Machine $M$ which solves $B$, there exists a Turing Machine $M'$ which may call $M$ as a subroutine a polynomial number of times and is also polynominal-time besides of calling $M$, such that the resulting function $f$ defined by $M'$ satisfies $(1)$ for all $w\in\Sigma^*$.

Question 1a: Are these two definitions equivalent? Clearly $\le_{p_1}$ is at least as stronger as $\le_{p_2}$. I would assume it is strictly stronger, because clearly $L^2 \le_{p_2} L$  for any Problem $L$, however I wouldn't assume the assertion holds for $\le_{p_1}$.

Question 1b: What if we restrict our problems to be in $NP$ (and assume $P\neq NP$)? Does that change anything? For the same reason I would assume no.

Question 2: What is the correct definition? I think definition 2 is the correct one which confuses me because most textbooks I have seen use definition 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition 1 is a [polynomial-time many-one reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-one_reduction), also known as a Karp reduction.  Definition 2 is a [Cook reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_reduction#Turing_reductions).

NP-completeness is defined with respect to Karp reductions.  If you found a textbook that defined NP-complete using Cook reduction, that textbook was wrong, or using a non-standard notion of NP-completeness.  I am sympathetic, but the term "NP-complete" has an accepted meaning in the field, and that meaning is based on Karp reductions.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness#Completeness_under_different_types_of_reduction, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/138/5038, [Can we construct a Karp reduction from a Cook reduction between NP problems?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/20074/755), [Teaching NP-completeness - Turing reductions vs Karp reductions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/16386/755), [Can one show NP-hardness by Turing reductions?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11120/755), [Graph problem known to be $NP$-complete only under Cook reduction](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/19069/755), [If you have a Cook reduction in both directions, do you also have a Karp reduction?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/62823/755), https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/686/5038, [If a problem is Cook-NP hard, and this problem is in NP, does it prove that the problem is Karp-NP-complete?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/84076/755).